# Jupyter Notebook export to HTML + Crontab doesn't show plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, cron

I am automating the automatic execution and HTML export of a Jupyter Notebook.
The Jupyter Notebook was created in VS Code and when I export it from the terminal in Ubuntu (jupyter nbconvert --execute  --to html) I get the correct HTML with all the plots.
However this does not happen when I execute it in the crontab or when use the terminal connected remotely from another PC with   ssh the plots are not shown. The script runs fine and outputs the print commands but not the plot.

The code goes like this:

```
for i in range(15):
    (... )
    np.log(pd_df+1).join(pd_df_2).plot()
    plt.show()
    plt.close()

    pd_df.join(pd_df_2).plot()
    plt.show()
    plt.close()

    np.clip(pd_df_3, -1, 1).plot()
    plt.show()
    plt.close()` 


   (...)
```

I tried to include the code bellow, I have executed in sh instead of bash.

```
%matplotlib inline # prior to import command
```

I also tried to include the code bellow but it also did not work.

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'notebook'
```

Comment: I get it works in the terminal of ubuntu. Let's set aside the crontab stuff for now. Can you explain better how/what you you mean by " the terminal in ssh"? Is the computer it is running on not Ubuntu. Is it a different environment in the ssh instance? The difference there is very unclear as of now. Minor: Your included first code block is not formatted well. And it is not a complete reproducible example. Everything after that first code block seems like it shouldn't be there or should be justified as to why you thought it would help given the two 'from the terminal' situations.

Comment: It means if I ssh to the machine where I am trying to run my code it also does not generate the chart. The charts are only generated when I open the terminal in the Ubuntu GUI.

Comment: Are the the same environments using the same underlying Python and packages?

Comment: Yes it is the same env. I manged to workarround it by adding a display as env variable like "DISPLAY=:0 /home/hugo/.local/bin/jupyter nbconvert --execute --to html ". Any idea how to support it without this?